# Wordpress Form Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't figure out what I'm missing here. It should be a simple form - 4 text fields and a checkbox.  However, every time I submit, I get the unexpected error.  I'd love to know where I messed up here.
Thanks so much!

```
<?php
function html_form_code() {
echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
echo '<div>';
echo '<div class="fleft">';
echo '<div class="labelgone"><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="textfield" placeholder="Name" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["name"] ) : '' ) . '" />';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="labelgone"><label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="textfield" placeholder="Email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["email"] ) : '' ) . '" />';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="fleft">';
echo '<div class="labelgone"><label for="company">Company</label><input type="text" name="company" id="textfield" placeholder="Company" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["company"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["company"] ) : '' ) . '" />';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="labelgone"><label for="telephone">Telephone</label><input type="text" name="telephone" id="textfield" placeholder="Telephone" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["telephone"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["telephone"] ) : '' ) . '" />';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div><br style="clear:both" />';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["checkbox"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["checkbox"] ) : '' ) . '" /><label for="checkbox1"><span></span>&nbsp;</label>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submitted" value="t"></p>';
echo '</form>';
}

function deliver_mail() {

// if the submit button is clicked, send the email
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {

    // get the blog administrator's email address
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

    // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<p>Thanks for contacting us, expect a response soon.</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
    }
}
}

function cf_shortcode() {
ob_start();
deliver_mail();
html_form_code();

return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'sitepoint_contact_form', 'cf_shortcode' );

?>
```

Comment: I see 2 issues with your form:
1) you're using regular variables that were passed through any scope in the function. Use $_POST['name'], etc.
2) I don't see where you are defining a value for $message. It looks like it is passing a blank value for your email body and wp_mail will not send out a blank email body.

Comment: Wouldn't $message be all of the fields together?

Comment: It would only be all of the fields together if you combined them yourself inside the function. Unless you're using some plugin or method i'm not aware of as I can only see the code you posted. Try defining the $message variable inside the deliver_mail() function as anything like $message = 'test 123';

Also I just noticed you have no subject defined, and no "to"... you'll need to define those as well.